# Show that this action is invariant under a symmetry transformation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, action

**Question Statement**

Consider the following Lagrangian for a classical system: 
$$\mathcal{L}(x,\dot{x})=\frac{1}{2}m\dot{x}^2-\frac{\alpha}{x^2}$$
Show that the action is invariant under the following symmetry transformations:
$$\begin{cases}t'=\frac{at+b}{ct+d}\\x'=\frac{1}{ct+d}x\end{cases}$$
With $\text{Det}\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}=1.$

**Attempt at a solution**

$$t'=\frac{at+b}{ct+d}\implies \text{d}t'=\frac{1}{(ct+d)^2}\text{d}t$$
$$x'=\frac{1}{ct+d}x\implies \text{d}x'=\frac{1}{ct+d}\text{d}x$$
Using both of these relations gives:
$$\implies \frac{\text{d}x'}{\text{d}t'}=\dot{x}'=(ct+d)\dot{x}$$
So,

$$\begin{align}S'(x',\dot{x}')&=\int^{t_2'}_{t_1'}\text{d}t'\mathcal{L}(x',\dot{x}')\\\\ &=\int^{t_2'}_{t_1'}\text{d}t'\bigg\{\frac{1}{2}m(\dot{x}')^2-\frac{\alpha}{x'^2}\bigg\}\\\\&=\int^{t_2'}_{t_1'}\frac{1}{(ct+d)^2}\text{d}t\bigg\{\frac{1}{2}m(ct+d)^2\dot{x}^2-(ct+d)^2\frac{\alpha}{x^2}\bigg\}\\\\&=\int^{t_2'}_{t_1'}\text{d}t\bigg\{\frac{1}{2}m\dot{x}^2-\frac{\alpha}{x^2}\bigg\}\\\\&=\int^{t_2'}_{t_1'}\text{d}t~\mathcal{L}(x,\dot{x})\end{align}$$

This is almost in the right form except for the time bounds in the integral. I'm probably missing something quite obvious but I just can't think of it right now, hopefully someone can point it out for me.

Is it simply that when I changed the integrating variable from $t'\rightarrow t$ the bounds also correspondingly change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't missing anything, your solution is perfect.

There is no need for the boundaries to have the same numerical values. Whenever $t$ transforms, so do the boundaries.

The important thing is: the value of the action doen't change (provided you didn't forget to adjust the boundaries, of course).
Also note that this doesn't have an impact on the equations of motion.

Comment: Ah, I knew it was something obvious like that. So technically, from the third line and downwards I should have unprimed times in the bounds of the integral?

Comment: @NormalsNotFar yup